# How to kill all the sub processes of bash script when it exits?

Tags: bash, shell, bash-trap

I am using named pipes to communicate between 3 kind of process: a producer, some readers and some writers. Then I created a script that simply it runs all the process, and I would like that when the run.sh process is killed or it terminates all the children process are killed too. The run.sh script follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
MAX_WRITERS=2
MAX_READERS=2

trap 'jobs -p | xargs kill' EXIT

./producer.sh &
for ((i=1; i<=$MAX_READERS; i++)); do ./reader_one.sh & done
for ((i=1; i<=$MAX_WRITERS; i++)); do ./writer_one.sh & done
wait
```

The script is very simple but seems it doesn't work because I can still see some processes running (just the producer.sh has been killed).

```
$ ./run.sh
... some activities ...
^C
$ ps aux | grep "[b]ash ./"
user         48909   ... /bin/bash ./writer_one.sh
user         48906   ... /bin/bash ./writer_one.sh
user         48904   ... /bin/bash ./reader_one.sh
user         48901   ... /bin/bash ./reader_one.sh
```

So I have to kill with this:

```
$ ps aux | grep "[b]ash ./" | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill
```

How can I make it works?

**Update 1:**
Seems the jobs that has been runned in background with `&` can resist to the signal `SIGINT`, so a simple `kill` is useless. Using `kill -9` or the `kill -TERM` in the trap they will receive the signal, but they remain alive, only the `producer.sh` has been killed properly.

```
./run.sh: line 21: 50039 Killed: 9               ./producer.sh
./run.sh: line 21: 50040 Killed: 9               ./reader_one.sh
./run.sh: line 21: 50041 Killed: 9               ./reader_one.sh
./run.sh: line 21: 50042 Killed: 9               ./writer_one.sh
./run.sh: line 21: 50043 Killed: 9               ./writer_one.sh

$ ps aux | grep "[b]ash ./"
user         50069   ... /bin/bash ./writer_one.sh
user         50068   ... /bin/bash ./writer_one.sh
user         50064   ... /bin/bash ./reader_one.sh
user         50061   ... /bin/bash ./reader_one.sh
```

**Update 2:**
`reader_one.sh` and `writer_one.sh` are just waiting for data in a named pipe.

**Update 3:**
Here the code of `read_one.sh` ; probably the reason is the subshell because of the pipe just before the `while`

```
init_read(){
...
}

read_one(){
...
}

init_reader
while true; do
  cat to_read | while read line; do
    read_one $line;
  done
done
```

Comment: Do they also resist `kill -9`? It seems like they do not die until the `producer.sh` properly terminates.. What is it doing exactly?

Comment: Using `kill -9` let them still alive. They (2 readers and 2 writers) are waiting for data from pipe

Comment: It looks like `reader_one.sh` and `writer_one.sh` create subshells. You're killing their main processes, but not the subprocesses.

Comment: `jobs -p` returns the process group leader id. Have you tried `jobs -p | xargs  -n1 pkill -g .`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The suggestion of @Barmar addressed me to the correct way. The problem was related to the subshell created by the piped while, so I changed this in `writer_one.sh` and `reader_one.sh`

```
cat to_read | while read line; do
    read_one $line;
done
```

to this:

```
while read line; do
    read_one $line;
done < to_read
```